# Smoothly transitioning header navigation classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I created this [site](http://holstee.com/blogs/mindful-matter) with a header that transitions using [jQuery Ui](https://jqueryui.com/) and [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). The idea is that there are two classes `.navbar-transparent` and `.navbar-white` and I use the [`.switchClass()`](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/) function that jQuery Ui Effects provides that transitions the change in the two classes when the scroll position of the page isn't at the top.

The problem however, the nav as it is now is, I believe the technical term is "janky". The transition isn't smooth, and when going from transparent to white the none of the font color doesn't transition at all, it just plops into black.

This shopify theme [Retina / Austin](http://retina-theme.myshopify.com/) does a great job of making that transition smooth with a css transition.

```
.header{
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Here's my javascript code:

```
mindful_matter.header = function() {
    if ($(".navbar-transparent").length == 0) return false;
    var callback = function() {
        var scrolled_val = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
        if (scrolled_val > 0) {
            $(".navbar").switchClass("navbar-transparent", "navbar-white");
        } else {
            $(".navbar").switchClass("navbar-white", "navbar-transparent");
        }
    }
    callback();
    $(window).scroll(callback);
}
```

Is there any way I can make the transition smoother? Using the setup I already have? Can I use a css transition when I have two classes that need to be swapped for one another?

Comment: Are you transitioning the font color at all? That seems to be your issue rather than anything else.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm transitioning between the two classes, that class controls everything within it including the font colors.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the classes CSS then. I suspect it doesn't include a transition of the font-color.

Comment: I think the main reason it looks strange is because the header turns white, so briefly you don't see the text.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here are the three less files that dictate all that is controlling the navbar https://gist.github.com/reggi/9213397 It's intense.

Comment: @ColinBacon I totally agree! How can I make the text change before the bg?

Comment: Hmmm...looks like the site has been updated with a transition on the `.navbar-nav > li > a`

Comment: @Paulie_D I updated it with the nav a's with `transition: all 0.25s ease;` I'm not seeing any change when it comes to the white text / white background situation. Perhaps the key is to slow down the white background, so it give the text some time to transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar{
    transition: background-color 500ms ease;
}
```